# How do I write a POST command in html without a form tag

Tags: html, post, tags

Okay so I have a form that takes a few inputs and upon submitting (by clicking a button) will open a new page. I want to auto open this page when the current page I am on is loaded (i.e. bypass pressing the submit button). I've already accomplished this through Javascript but that's not working well for me. Most browsers recognize this new window as a pop-up and try to block it. Also in Chrome the page is loaded in a new window (one of those display only windows) when i'd rather have it open in a new tab like how it works through the form tag.

I would like to write a post command in html with the inputs I have to automatically open the page I need just like how its done through a form tag but without requiring the form so that the window can be autogenerated.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Use [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "some.php",
   data: { name: "donald", location: "Wuppertal" }
   }).done(function( msg ) {
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   });
 </script>
```